# Excel: if year X, then sum values from multiple rows

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum

I have a table with projects, each project has multiple work packages. I need to create a formula or pivot table with the following condition:

- if year is 2015 or 2016, sum the work package amounts and show the total for the project

The result should be as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: use the Sumifs() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this using Pivot table...?

[image]

Select `2015` and `2016` from filter.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you. I tried Pivot before but it was not calculating amount since I have "VALUE" errors

Comment: Glad to help... :)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to use a formula, use SUMIFS as Luuklag suggested. For your example, assuming the layout is like this

[image]

it would be this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D2:D6,C2:C6,{2015,2016},A2:A6,A10))
```

The reason is that SUMIFS by default uses only AND logic, so you need to use an array, and then an outer sum (see [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) for more).

Comment: Entered with `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`?

Comment: No need - just tested it.

Comment: Ah, the explicit array `{2015,2016}` makes it so you don't need to. I use this often but refer to a range, in which case you need the `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`.